# Updating fields efficiently without losing data

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm getting my feet wet with pymongo, and this seems like an easy task but I'm not sure the best way to do it.

I have a dictionary of `Member` objects, each of which has a dictionary (key-value pairs of data). I would like to go through my dictionary of `Member` objects, and update the database:

1. Writing every field present in the `Member` object into the DB, and
2. Leaving unchanged any other fields present in the DB for that Member id which are not present in the `Member` object.

Here's my best shot, but running it is *extremely* slow, so I'm guessing there's a better way. (Maybe even a one-liner?)

In this code, `self.members` is the dictionary of members I'm iterating through, and `member.structure()` returns a dictionary of that `Member` object's data.

```
for m in sorted(self.members.values(), key=lambda val:val.session) : ## for each member
    if mcollection.find_one({'id':m.id}) is None: ## if there is no db entry matching the member id
        print("\tMember {0} wasn't present in the db. Inserting.".format(m.id))
        mcollection.insert(m.structure())         ## insert the full dictionary
    else: ## if there is a matching db entry
        for (k,v) in m.structure().items():  ## for each entry in the member's dictionary
            mcollection.update( {'id':m.id}, {'$set': {k:v}}, upsert=True  ) ## set the member's field to its value given in the dictionary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
for (k,v) in m.structure().items():  ## for each entry in the member's dictionary
    mcollection.update( {'id': 'm.id'}, {'$set': {k:v}}, upsert=True  ) ## set the member's field to its value given in the dictionary
```

Yes, this is insane. For every k/v pair you make a separate request! You should be setting them all at once.

```python
mcollection.update( {'id': 'm.id'}, {'$set': m.structure()})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's super great! It seems like that command does not update dotted fields (i.e. dictionaries within the structure dictionary). Is there a way to update all fields from the structure dictionary, including sub-dictionaries?

Comment: @Spiky: just flatten your dictionaries (make them dotted names) `$set: {'field1.field2.field3': 1}` should work